# conditional programs- designing function that calculates sales tax?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to design a function that calculates sales tax. So it would consume the price thats on sale and also the tax percentage as a ,decimal or a fraction, and it would produce the final price. So If I give 20 and 105 percent ( 1.05), I would get 21.

(define (sales a b)
  (* a b))

I got the decimal part down, but how would I get it to do the fraction part?

like If I give 20 and 5/100, how would I get to make compute 21? I need it to recognize the fractions... if this makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
(define (sales a b)
  (if (exact? b)
      (* a (add1 b))
      (* a b)))
```

It works as expected:

```
(sales 20 1.05)
=> 21

(sales 20 5/100)
=> 21
```

Comment: @BrandonMick great! please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you, by clicking on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to "recognize" the fraction: all arithmetic functions already do it for you.

```
% racket 
Welcome to Racket v5.3.1.
> (* 20 (+ 1 5/100))
21
```